# scikit learn regression .predict() return type not consistent

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.6

I am running three different regression models from sklearn.linear_model.

linear_model.LinearRegression.predict() and linear_model.Ridge.predict() both return the same format of (1300,**1**) in my specific example.

linear_model.Lasso.predict() when passed the exact same input data return a (1300,).  This causes errors in my program and my plotting fails.

I have tried making sure I am indeed passing the same format of data by inspect with np.shape() every variable used.  I have traced it back to the return values from .predict() that are different.

```
# Crashes when .Lasso is included in mdls
# If I only have the first two in the list (LinearRegression and Ridge) it run and plots fine.
mdls=[linear_model.LinearRegression, linear_model.Ridge, linear_model.Lasso]
argdic=[{'fit_intercept':True},{'fit_intercept':True,'alpha':.5},{'fit_intercept':True,'alpha':0.1}]  
i=0      

for m,a in zip(mdls,argdic):

    ## Run regression Fit
    res=m(**a).fit(xsk,ysk)

    predZmesh=res.predict(meshpts)

    predZact=res.predict(actpts)




    reZ=ysk['Eff. At Rated Lift'].values.reshape(len(ysk['Eff. At Rated Lift']),1)

    zerr=np.subtract(predZact,reZ)
    zerr_r=zerr.ravel()


    #Normalize the errror for colormap
    nrm=colors.Normalize(vmin=zerr_r.min(),vmax=zerr_r.max())

    r2=res.score(xsk,ysk)

    #Setup Plot
    ax=fig.add_subplot(1,len(mdls),i+1,projection='3d')

    #Plot scatter of actual data points
    #ax.scatter(xsk['Minor Comp. At Temp'],xsk['Major Comp. At Temp'],ysk,marker='o',alpha=0.9)
    print('Shape of x,y,z,err.ravel={0},{1},{2},{3}'.format(np.shape(xsk['Minor Comp. At Temp']),np.shape(xsk['Major Comp. At Temp']),np.shape(ysk['Eff. At Rated Lift']),np.shape(zerr_r)))

    ax.scatter(xsk['Minor Comp. At Temp'],xsk['Major Comp. At Temp'],ysk['Eff. At Rated Lift'],c=zerr_r,norm=nrm,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu'),marker='o',alpha=0.9)



    ax.plot_surface(xmeshpts,ymeshpts,
          predZmesh.reshape(xmeshpts.shape),color='red',alpha=0.1)

    i+=1
```

Should the regression function not return data in the same format?  When I read over the documentation it shows the format to be consistent.  Can anyone please confirm that my expectation of consistent return values is true?  Then I can proceed with debugging.

Comment: In my experience sometimes predictions are outputted as a flat list, sometimes as a single column -- the shape of predictions depends on the algorithm. Feel free to add a link to the specific page in the sklearn docs you were reviewing if you'd like a second set of eyes to give it a sanity check. I recommend just reshaping the predictions of linear_model.Lasso.predict() and then seeing if the graph is in line with your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5058), originally reported in 2015.  The problem occurs when you supply a y_array with 2 dimensions (test_y.shape=(n, 1)).

The simplest solution is to flatten your y_array before calling the .predict() method:

```
test_y = test_y.flatten()
```

(Assuming test_y is a numpy array)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition that checks and then reshapes the output of the predictions if the model being used is `linear_model.Lasso`.

The following code could be used to perform the reshape: `x = x.reshape(-1,1)`.

Here's a simple example:

If you have a flattened array with no columns like this:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
```

The output of `x.shape` would of course be `(3,)`.

We could then reshape it so that the values are stored as a single column with shape `(3,1)`:

```
x = x.reshape(-1,1)
```

After this, the output of `x.shape` is now `(3, 1)`.

Visually, instead of being a flat list, the array now contains a column:

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```